# CSS align dropdown submenu to justified menu

Tags: html, css

I am having issues getting a dropdown sub-menu to align correctly on my site. As can be seen here (http://jsfiddle.net/rjgunning/ehjm3t9s/2/)

The parent menu of the dropdown is fully justified. Before fully justifying this everything aligned correctly.
Floating left does not seem to make the dropdown menu align with the left of the parent list element. I am currently setting its position using `margin-left: 120px`

Can anyone see what I missed?

This is the relevant CSS for my menu

```
nav#subnav ul.menu {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    list-style: none;
}
nav#subnav ul.menu li.menu-item {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    float:none;
}

/* --- Drop-down Menu --- */
nav#subnav ul.menu li.menu-item ul.sub-menu{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

nav#subnav ul.menu li.menu-item:hover ul{ 
    display: block;
}

nav#subnav ul.menu li.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu li.menu-item{ 
    float: left;
    margin-left: 120px; /* Needs fixed properly*/
}

nav#subnav ul.menu:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Menu html:

```
<nav id="subnav">
    <div class="menu-sub-menutmp-container">
        <ul id="menu-sub-menutmp" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1414" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="...">About the MCR</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-1015" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Committee 2014/15</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1116" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1414" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1414" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1414" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1414" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1414" class="menu-item"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
</ul></div> </nav>
```

EDIT: added html menu
EDIT2: added jsfiddle example

Comment: Please post menu HTML also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it

needed to add

```
nav#subnav ul.menu li.menu-item-has-children {
    position: relative
}
```